# Using play and restlet together

Tags: heroku, playframework, jetty, restlet, playframework-2.0

I've developed a pretty extensive rest API using restlet, but now I need to serve web pages. I've looking into the play framework and it seems like a pretty good solution to my problem. There's a lot of code to share so I'd like to have both running from the same server/jvm (for eventual deployment on Heroku.

Is it possible to configure the application server, like jetty, to split the calls up based on URL path to go to either restlet or play? If so how? Do I start with a play project or a restlet project, and how do I modify it?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options here

1. You could use a fronted Apache layer, so that you can completely separate the Restlet part from your Play part. As you are deploying to Heroku though, I am not sure if you will be able to do this as Heroku doesn't give you a fronted http layer
2. Modify the HTTP handler. This would involve creating your own module or modifying the core source of Play. This certainly would solve your use case, but I don't think modifying core is a great answer, and the module approach is quite overkill.
3. Using Play 1.x you could have a single controller action for all your Restlet API that simply calls your Restlet services. In Play 2.x you can use the Global object onRouteRequest method.

If you are thinking of deploying to a PaaS like Heroku, I think I would go with option 3.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Two questions: 1. is there also an option to do something at the app server level? (jetty/netty/tomcat/whatever) 2. I've looked a bit at option 3, and I like the idea, but I don't see a way to convert the request and response objects from play to something useable by restlet.

Comment: 1) That is pretty much what option 2 is. Netty exposes a http handler. 2) I have not played with Restlet, but as I understand it, it is app server agnostic

Comment: Ah. okay, guess I misunderstood option 2. yes, restlet is app server agnostinc, but I'm still not clear how you go from play.mvc.context, and play.mvc.Http.Request (available to onRequest and action.call) and call into restlet with that, but I will mark this as correct and start a new question. Thanks again for your terrific answer!

Comment: my other question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166394/using-plays-global-onrouterequest-to-handle-restlet-calls